# SQL Server unpivot columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table that I would like to unpivot in a SQL statement. It consists of a person and phone 1 through 5. Right now I'm doing a union for each phone but I fear it is causing performance issues.

Columns:

```
PERSON_GUID, 
PHONE_1, PHONE_1_VOICE_FLG, 
PHONE_2, PHONE_2_VOICE_FLG, 
PHONE_3, PHONE_3_VOICE_FLG, 
PHONE_4, PHONE_4_VOICE_FLG, 
PHONE_5, PHONE_5_VOICE_FLG
```

How would I best unpivot the row with performance in mind so that the results are:

```
PERSON_GUID, PHONE_NO, VOICE_FLG
```

Comment: have you tried using the PIVOT/UNPIVOT command https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Should be unpivot

Comment: @marc_s if the OP is using UNION than he is doing unpivot. please rollback.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: what do you think I should "roll back"?? I just tried to clean up the presentation, and replaced the "mssql" with the proper product name - **SQL Server** - I didn't change anything else.....

Comment: I agree this sounds like unpivot for multiple columns.  Jonesk perhaps you can add some sample data and desired result to clarify?

Comment: ideally i want to use unpivot but i'm having a hard time understanding Microsoft's documentation.

Comment: @marc_s, I thought there were other changes. No big deal :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer `UNPIVOT` but as for your solution -
Make sure you are using `UNION ALL` and not `UNION`.
`UNION ALL` just spills one query result after the other.
`UNION` eliminates rows duplications and this is where you pay in performance.

---

```
select  PERSON_GUID,PHONE_NO,
        case right(col,1)
            when 1 then PHONE_1_VOICE_FLG
            when 2 then PHONE_2_VOICE_FLG
            when 3 then PHONE_3_VOICE_FLG
            when 4 then PHONE_4_VOICE_FLG
            when 5 then PHONE_5_VOICE_FLG
        end VOICE_FLG

from    t unpivot (PHONE_NO for col in
            (PHONE_1,PHONE_2,PHONE_3,PHONE_4,PHONE_5)) u
```

Comment: I think the problem is though that both phone for (Phone_1, Phone_2, etc.) needs to be unpivoted and VOICE_FLG for (Phone_1_Voice_FLG, Phone_2_Voice_Flg, etc) needs to be unpivot.  So it would take a double unpivot operation or just union all statements as OP mentioned they are doing.

Comment: Thanks @Matt :-) I did a total mess here. Fixed now