# SQL server convert one single row to column

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, how can I convert one single row of integer data, like this

```
ColumnName1    ColumnName2    ColumnName3
    1               2              3
```

into a single row, order by DSEC?

```
ColumnNameTotalSort
        3
        2
        1
```

I know the requirement seems simple but I have been struggling for a while.

Thanks for input.

Comment: Look up how to UNPIVOT in SQL Server. The ORDER BY isn't a big issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server unpivot columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40936369/sql-server-unpivot-columns)

Answer (score 1):

As ZLK mentioned, UNPIVOT is an option

Another option is with a `CROSS APPLY` and `VALUES`

**Example**

```
Select B.* 
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (values (ColumnName1)
                    ,(ColumnName2)
                    ,(ColumnName3)
             ) B(ColumnNameTotalSort)
 -- Where Your Filter Condition Here
 Order By ColumnNameTotalSort Desc
```

**Returns**

```
ColumnNameTotalSort
3
2
1
```

Comment: @UsernameNotExist Happy to help